# ios check if array has object

Tags: ios, objective-c

From an array, I want to make a new mutable array holding all the items that meet a certain criteria. That's not the problem. The problem is checking if the array is empty.

```
   if (!theDates]) {/*do something*/}
```

it comes back positive regardless, because the mutable array was created. But

```
    if (![theDates objectAtIndex:0]) 
    {
        /* nothing got added to the array, so account for that */
    } 
    else 
    {
        /* do something with the array */
    }
```

It crashes.

Comment: if you've found a solution in one of the answers, don't forget to accept it in order to remove your question from the Unanswered section.

Answer (score 5):

This crashes because although you have allocated your array, it's still empty. The line `[theDates objectAtIndex:0]` is trying to access the first object of an array, and due your array has none yet, it will crash.

To check the integrity of your array, just do this:

```
if (theDates.count > 0)
{
    //Do something

    id object = theDates[0]; //this for sure won't crash
}
```

Comment: You don't need the 1st half of the check. Just do `if (theDates.count) {`

Comment: You are right. In early ages access a property of a nil pointer will cause a crash, that's no longer necessary

Comment: You don't even need the `> 0` for this check. Of course it's not wrong but it's not needed either.

Comment: Yeah, that I do know. Although, I prefer to keep the `> 0` in my codes, you write two more characters but you gain in legibility. It's a matter of opinion in fact, both will work

Answer (score 1):

Use `[theDates count] > 0`. You're accessing a possibly non-existent element, so it will crash when it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

`if (theDates != nil){
if (theDates.count > 0){ 
'do something' 
}
}`

This should check null array then check empty array which prevents nullpointerexception arises

Comment: You don't need the 1st `if` statement. And it is standard convention to use `nil`, not `null` when dealing with Cocoa/Cocoa-touch object pointers.

Comment: Ooops, I'd forgot to switch my convention mindset from java to Obj-C, editted

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the lastObject method which will return nil if the array is empty

```
if (![theDates lastObject]) { do something }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( (theDates!=nil) && (theDates.count > 0))
{
  //We have and existing array and something in there..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine..

```
if (!URarray || !URarray.count){
  // write code here
}
```